# Activate bluetooth Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

I have an Olivetti P75 pc and i can't use Bluetooth on ubuntu.
I get no bluetooth info from `sudo rfkill list`

From `bluetoothctl` whatever command i execute i get `No default controller available`

Some Info:
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Result:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0890] (rev c4)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN [8086:4022]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
--
05:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:2706]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.029860] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.066626] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   11.336561] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   11.801005] psmouse serio2: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x250f01)
[10958.656381] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[10958.656402] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[10958.656405] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[10958.656407] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[10958.656412] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[11014.125193] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[11014.125194] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[11014.125197] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Do you get the same results if you run bluetoothctl as root? i.e.: `sudo bluetoothctl`

Comment: @JaradDowning yes same results

Comment: I looked up the Olivetti P75 and I cannot find any specs. Is the bluetooth internal or via USB? Are you seeing any error messages in syslog or dmesg that would link to bluetooth not functioning?

Comment: @JaradDowning nothing on syslog, from dmesg i just see what i've wrote above

Comment: If the wifi is actually a 2200 Intel, it doesn't have bluetooth as back then the cards only had bluetooth when the third digit of the model number was a 3

Comment: See if you can find a USB bluetooth dongle, they are very inexpensive. I don't think that system came with bluetooth and if it did, it isn't working.